# Treatment of NA values when grouping in dplyr in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large data set with a handful of duplicate rows -- more than one row for the pair of variables that I want to serve as primary keys (eg., id (the subject) and TT (the time period)).  I need to pick one row to keep.  One strategy is to keep the one with the largest value on one variable.  The variable may be missing for some subjects and I do not want to drop these subjects.  Using the group_by() and filter(testvar == max(testvar)) drops the subjects with a missing test var, which I do not want.  One approach that works is to set the missing values to -99999, and do the group and filter, and then set the -99999 back to NA, but this is a bit of a hack.  Is there a better approach? Here is what I tried:

```
dsn <- data.frame(id = rep(1:2, each = 4), TT = rep(c(1,2,2,3),  2), testVar = 1:8)

dsn
```

this data set has two subjects with 3 time periods but the second time period is repeated.  I want id and TT to work as primary keys going forward.

```
dsn2 <- dsn %>%
  group_by(id, TT) %>%
  filter(testVar == max(testVar))
dsn2
```

this works fine as for the second time period it keeps the row with the biggest value of testVar.  Now I set the value of testVar to NA for the first subject:

```
dsn$testVar[1:4] <- NA
dsn

dsn2 <- dsn %>%
  group_by(id, TT) %>%
  filter(testVar == max(testVar))
dsn2
```

which drops the first subject which I do not want. If I replace the na with -9999, it works and then replace the -9999 with NA, I get what I want:

```
dsn$testVar[is.na(dsn$testVar) == T] <- -99999
dsn2 <- dsn %>%
  group_by(id, TT) %>%
  filter(testVar == max(testVar))
dsn2$testVar[dsn2$testVar == -99999] <- NA

dsn2
```

which works, but is a *hack*.  Is there a more elegant approach?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `filter()`, use `slice_max()`:

```
library(dplyr) # > v1.1.0

dsn %>%
  slice_max(testVar, by = c(id, TT))
```

```
# A tibble: 7 × 3
     id    TT testVar
  <int> <dbl>   <int>
1     1     1      NA
2     1     2      NA
3     1     2      NA
4     1     3      NA
5     2     1       5
6     2     2       7
7     2     3       8
```

As @TarJae points out, this works because of the behavior of the `na_rm` argument, which is `FALSE` by default. Per [the docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html):

> If `FALSE`, `NA` values are sorted to the end (like in `arrange()`), so they will only be included if there are insufficient non-missing values to reach `n`/`prop`.

Also note that `slice_max()` handles ties more easily than `filter()` — set `with_ties = FALSE` to keep just the first row when there are ties (such as for rows 2 and 3 here).

Comment: @zephryl This is very good. Do you think we have also to consider the default `na.rm=FALSE` also as important beside the `with_ties` argument?

Comment: Thanks! Good point, I’ve added a note about that.

Answer (score 2):

Try `%in%` instead of `==`.

*Using base R.*

```
dsn[with(dsn, testVar %in% ave(testVar, id, TT, FUN=max)), ]
#   id TT testVar
# 1  1  1      NA
# 2  1  2      NA
# 3  1  2      NA
# 4  1  3      NA
# 5  2  1       5
# 7  2  2       7
# 8  2  3       8
```

*Using `dplyr` (you were close).*

```
library(dplyr)
dsn %>%
  group_by(id, TT) %>%
  filter(testVar %in% max(testVar))
# # A tibble: 7 × 3
# # Groups:   id, TT [6]
#      id    TT testVar
#   <int> <dbl>   <int>
# 1     1     1      NA
# 2     1     2      NA
# 3     1     2      NA
# 4     1     3      NA
# 5     2     1       5
# 6     2     2       7
# 7     2     3       8
```

---

*Data:*

```
dsn <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), TT = c(1, 
2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3), testVar = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: > x1 = NA
> x2 = NA
> x1 == x2
[1] NA #returns NA
> x1 %in% x2
[1] TRUE. #returns TRUE

Comment: What do you want to tell me with this?

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful, I didn't know that %in% is a bit different than  == when there is just one element in the vector of comparison.  The above was my test.

Comment: @DashdotdotDashdotdot `c(NA, 2) %in% 2` yields `c(FALSE, TRUE)` whereas `c(NA, 2) == 2` gives `c(NA, TRUE)`. Be careful though, in other cases we want the `NA`s, so use it wisely and not generally.